# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error when saving NSMutableArray In custom object saved in NSUserDefaults in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsobject

I have created a custom object that consists of a string, int, UIImage. I tried to add a NSMutable array and when tried to run my project i got an error. "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)".
how can I prevent this error and have this nsmutablearray in this class?

Here is my class:

```
class develop : NSObject, NSCoding {

    var power: Int!
    var name: String!
    var image: UIImage!
    var flag: UIImage!
    var militaryName: String!

    var relations: NSMutableArray!


    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeInteger(power, forKey:"power")
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey:"name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(image, forKey:"image")
        aCoder.encodeObject(flag, forKey: "flag")
        aCoder.encodeObject(militaryName, forKey: "militaryName")
        aCoder.encodeObject(relations, forKey: "relations")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init()

        power = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("power")
        name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        image = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("image")as! UIImage
        flag = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("flag") as! UIImage
        militaryName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("militaryName") as! String
        relations = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("relations") as! NSMutableArray
    }
}
```

here is the setting of the objects:

```
func setUpDefaults(){
    //Afghanistan
    Afghanistan.power = 0
    Afghanistan.name = "Afghanistan"
    Afghanistan.image = UIImage(named: "afghan_flag.jpg")!
    Afghanistan.flag = UIImage(named: "afghan_flag.jpg")!
    Afghanistan.militaryName = "Afghan Military"
    Afghanistan.relations = [New_Zealand]
}
```

Here is the loading:

```
class Test:UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //Afganistan


    setUpDefaults()
    let developData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(Afghanistan)
    NSUserDefaults().setObject(developData, forKey: "Afg")


    if let loadedData = NSUserDefaults().dataForKey("Afg") {
        if let loadedDevelop = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(loadedData) as? develop{
            Label.text = Afghanistan.militaryName
            imageView.image = loadedDevelop.flag
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  If it's one that references `relations`, check to be sure the variable is not NULL.

Comment: @PhillipMills Its the one that references `power`

Comment: OK...same concept, put a breakpoint on the crashing line and check to see that everything it's going to reference is non-NULL.