# Objective-C: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error in encodeWithCoder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-catalina

There are lots of questions about this error (`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0`), but they are all about code written in Swift, and this is pure Objective-C. The answers mostly seem to be about "unwrapping nil" which apparently is something that cannot be done in Swift, but doesn't seem to have a direct counterpart in Objective-C.

I never had this error before "upgrading" to Catalina and Xcode 12 (from 10). It seems to happen randomly, after a few minutes, at different places in the code, but usually somewhere in the `encodeWithCoder` method when encoding one of the NSMutableArrays:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeInt:serial_version forKey:@"version"];

    [encoder encodeObject:program_name forKey:@"program_name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:program_info forKey:@"program_info"];
    [encoder encodeObject:story_name forKey:@"story_name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:story_title forKey:@"story_title"];

    [encoder encodeObject:_windows forKey:@"windows"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_streams forKey:@"streams"];

...
```

Original code [here](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/master/glkimp/autorestore/TempLibrary.m#L169-L195).

I guess makes it similar to [Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error when saving NSMutableArray In custom object saved in NSUserDefaults in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954916/thread-1exc-bad-instruction-error-when-saving-nsmutablearray-in-custom-object-s) . Again, it works for a while, encoding everything just fine, and then suddenly crashes.

EDIT: Stack trace [here](https://pastebin.com/aFjaWu3r).

Comment: Can you add a stack trace from the crash to your question?  (Type "bt" in the debugger console when the program stops.)

Comment: I'm guessing some of those objects that you try to encode are nil?

Comment: They should not be nil, but they are arrays of Obj-C objects with properties that may be nil.

Comment: According to the trace, the problem involves `-[TempStream encodeWithCoder:]` which does something with a URL, causing memory problems.  Not being familiar with the code, I can't guess at much more.  Maybe turning on Xcode's address sanitizer for the target would help catch the error.

Comment: When using encoding/decoding i would go for `NSSecureCoding` or at least `NSCoding` protocol. All interfaces in source in folder autorestore do not declare they are conform.

Comment: Rewriting the code to conform to NSSecureCoding does indeed seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Ol Sen in a comment, rewriting the code to conform to NSSecureCoding (basically replacing `decodeObjectForKey:` with `decodeObjectOfClass:forKey`) seems to fix the problem.